# One-liner with Strange Output -- What's going on with strings as 'this'?

Tags: javascript

I found interesting output when I set `this` to a string using `apply` and then `console.log`'d it. What's up?

In Chrome's Javascript console,

```
(function(){ return this }).apply("hello");
```

Outputs to:

```
String {0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o"}
```

Why isn't it `"hello"` like I would have expected?

Interestingly, checking this output with `typeof`:

```
typeof (function(){ return this }).apply("hello");
```

Gives me `"object"`, instead of `"string"`.

I'm guessing that is some wizardry with `apply` that I don't understand?

Comment: Side-question: is my question title's leading "Javascript:" redundant, useless, and annoying, considering the lonesome `javascript` tag? I'm beginning to feel self-conscious about it.

Comment: There's no need for it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the argument for `this` is passed in non-strict mode, it is converted to an object, so it's returning a string object, which is different from a string value. Each index in a string object corresponds to the characters of a string value, in order.  To convert it back to a "normal" string, just call `toString()` on it - that makes it a string value like you're used to.

This does not occur in ES5 strict mode (when you insert `'use strict'` at the beginning of your program or function), as in that mode arguments are not coerced to objects, but given directly.

```
// if you're not passing any arguments, it doesn't matter whether you use apply or call
(function () { return this; }).call("see"); // { 0: "s", 1: "e", 2: "e" }, plus some other special properties
(function () { return this.toString(); }).call("see"); // "see"
(function () { 'use strict'; return this; }).call("see"); // "see", where strict mode is supported
```

Reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3 (note that the `ThisBinding` refers to the value of the `this` keyword inside the function).

Comment: Aside from `typeof` resulting in an `"object"`, are there further consequences to using a string object like one would a string primitive?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: there are a few small effects (relating to it being an object and not its own string), but overall it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from MDN article on [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that **this may not
>   be the actual value seen by the method**: if the method is a function in
>   non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the
>   global object, and **primitive values will be boxed**.

This means that string primitive is being boxed into String object. To provide original string as this, you'll have to enforce strict mode:

```
(function(){ "use strict"; return this }).apply("hello"); // "hello"
```